# How to find the last table cell which doesn't have text value and put a message?

Tags: javascript, tablerow

I want to detect the last table row cell of a table which doesn't have any value (text).

```
var all_product_cell = document.getElementsByClassName("product-cell");
        for (var i = 0; i < all_product_cell.length; i++) {
            var td = all_product_cell[i];
            alert(all_product_cell.length);              
        }
```

This code returns the table rows length... but I don't know how to check the last row which is clean and put there a message "hello!"...

UPDATE :

With this code system find last cell and put HELLO, but how I check the last cells who haven't text value and put the Hello there?

```
            var all_local_cell = document.getElementsByClassName("product-cell");
        for (var i = 0; i < all_local_cell.length; i++) {
            var td = all_local_cell[i];
            total_rows = all_local_cell.length-1;
            all_product_cell[total_rows].value = "HELLO";
```

Comment: if possible give your html code which has table design. It will be helpful to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can get last row of table by using below line :

```js
var product_table = document.getElementsByClassName("product-cell");
console.log(product_table); 

    for (var i = 0; i < product_table.length; i++) {
           total_rows = product_table[i].rows.length;
           last_row = product_table[i].rows[total_rows-1];
           last_row_length = last_row.cells.length;
           last_column = last_row.cells[last_row_length-1]; // directly get last cell
           If(last_column.innerHTML() == “”){
               last_column.innerHTML = “Hello friend”;
            }
           console.log(last_column.innerHTML);
           for(var j =0;j<last_row.cells.length;j++){ // you can find through loop using which cells is empty 

             console.log(last_row.cells[j]);
           }
          // console.log(last_row);
        }
```

If you give html code will help better way.

https://codepen.io/aviboy2006/pen/ZEYBWWE

Comment: No need to use jQuery for this ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 thank you for the answer friend, on your example on Country delete the last 3 cells and system must be put "hello" message down of the Austria right?

Comment: Once u get last cell or any cell u can do operation on it

Comment: @aviboy2006 and the operation who find the last cell who haven't text and put a message there can you help me on this ?

Comment: Added if case to find if it last cell is empty then set value.

Answer (score 0):

```
const productTable = document.querySelector(".your-product-table"); // get the table
const textOnLastCell = productTable
  .rows[productTable.rows.lenght -1] // get last row
  .cells[productTable.rows[productTable.rows.lenght -1].cells.lenght -1] // get last cell of last row
  .innerText // get inner text
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a table with two empty TD'S.

The function will get an array of all TD's with the class product-cell and loop through each cell and check if innerHTML is empty, and then it will set lastTD to the last empty TD and set its innerHTML to "Hallo"

```js
setTextLastEmptyCell()

function setTextLastEmptyCell(){

  let tds = document.getElementsByClassName('product-cell')

  for(let td of tds){

    if(td.innerHTML === '') lastTD = td

  }

  lastTD.innerHTML = 'HALLO'

}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td class="product-cell">ABC</td>
<td class="product-cell">DEF</td>
<td class="product-cell">CBA</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="product-cell"></td>
<td class="product-cell">CDA</td>
<td class="product-cell">ACB</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="product-cell">ABC</td>
<td class="product-cell"></td>
<td class="product-cell">DEF</td>
</tr>
</table>
```